# unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int' python

Tags: python, audio, binary, steganography, lsb

I have an lsb steganography function to hide messages that have been modulated into audio. the results of the modulation are binary numbers 1 and 0. when I run the function I get an error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

here's my code:

```
def lsb(bineraudio, binermod):
    # bineraudio = 0000000000000000000000000001100001100110011101000111100101110000011001000110000101110011011010000000000000000000000000000000000001101001011100110110111100110110011011010111000000110100001100010000
    # binermod = 1111000010101111110000000110111110001111110111110100111111100000000000000101000000110000011011111000000000101111010000001110
    for i, bit in enumerate(binermod):
        bineraudio[i] = (bineraudio[i] & 254) | bit
    # Get the modified bytes
    frame_modified = bytes(bineraudio)

    with open('txt/'+'binary.txt', 'w') as file1: 
        file1.write(frame_modified.bin)

# variables binarypass and binaryaudio contain the binary digits 1 and 0.
```

how do I fix the error or how to insert a message that has been modulated into the song using lsb?
i was trying lsb method using [this](https://gist.github.com/sumit-code/c3d5f27fdeda44dd0922e14263ede4c4)

Comment: Try this: ```bineraudio[i] = (int(bineraudio[i]) & 254) | bit```, also, please consider adding more of the code.

Comment: still same error @Meh

Answer (score 0):

`bineraudio` and `binermod` are both strings, like `"01010101..."`, which is how you're able to index them and iterate over them. However, [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) ([like `&`, `|`, `<<`, `>>`, and so on](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)) take numeric values. So, once you get the bit you're interested in (`bineraudio[i]`), try simply casting it to an `int` by calling `int(bineraudio[i])`, so that you can perform the bitwise `&` with 254, which is of course already an integer. You'll have to do something similar with `bit`, since it is also a character of a string.

In summary, your lines 4 and 5 should look like this instead:

```py
for i, bit in enumerate(binermod):
    bineraudio[i] = (int(bineraudio[i]) & 254) | int(bit)
```

Comment: ah i see, but i still got error. but the error changes : 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: or do you know how to save it into array? for example i have int "01010101...", i want to change it into :
biner = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...]

Comment: `biner = [int(c) for c in "01010101"]`